# Reducing Overhead When Calling Python Functions from Node.js Using spawnSync

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.10 and have a file named `utilities.py` in my project directory that contains several functions and import statements. I import its content to use in other Python files as shown in the snippet below where I am showing you the content of the `validate_user.py` file. I am doing this in a setup where I call Python functions from the JS environment with the help of the `spawnSync` function in nodeJS (as shown below) to pass the arguments from the JS environment to the Python environment. But the problem is that the process takes too long to execute.

For example, validation of a user based on credentials stored in a sqlite DB (see the validate_user() function below) takes about 12-13 seconds. In this example, the DB is small, just containing data for a single user. However, when I use an alternate approach to validate a user based on the credentials saved in my .bashrc (see the validate_user_env() function below) the validation is almost instantaneous!

Furthermore, when I try bringing all the necessary functions and library imports in the `validate_user.py` file from `utilities.py` then the DB way of validation is also instantaneous!

As a last experiment, I copied the import statements (25 or so) from `utilities.py` to `validate_user.py` just to check how does it affect and this time again the validation took longer which indicates that the import statements in `validate_user.py` is the main reason for the delay.

How can I resolve this? In my real project, I call many Python functions distributed in several files using the `spawnSync` approach described earlier. Many of them use common functions defined in other files that also contain multiple import statements, so it does not make sense to duplicate codes across different files. What could be a good strategy to solve this?

```
// JS code to call Python
function callSync(PYTHON_PATH, script, args, options) {
  const result = spawnSync(PYTHON_PATH, [script, JSON.stringify(args)]);
  if (result.status === 0) {
    const ret = result.stdout.toString();
    if (!(ret instanceof Error)) {
      return ret;
    } else {
      return {
    error: ret.message
      };
    }
  } else if (result.status === 1) {
    return {
      error: result.stderr.toString()
    };
  } else {
    return {
      error: result.stdout.toString()
    };
  }
}


## Below is the content of validate_user.py
import argparse
import json
import os
import utilities as ut

## This function uses a DB to validate
def validate_user(args):
     ## Get the arguments from JS
     username = args.get('username')
     password = args.get('password')
     res = ut.validate_user_password(username, password)
     result = {
     "greeting": "Hello from validate_user.py!",
     "code": res["code"],
     "message": res["msg"]
     }
     print(json.dumps(result))


## This function uses env valiables to validate
def validate_user_env(args):
    ## Get the arguments from JS
    username_in = args.get('username')
    password_in = args.get('password')

    ## Get the credentials from env vars
    username = os.getenv("my_username")
    password = os.getenv("my_password")

    ## validate and return
    if username_in == username and password_in == password:
    result = {"greeting": "Hello from validate_user.py!", "code": "success", "message": "Authentication successful"}
    else:
    result = {"greeting": "Hello from validate_user.py!", "code": "failure", "message": "Invalid username or password"}

    print(json.dumps(result))


## Set up argument parser object and fetch the args   
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('json_args')
args = parser.parse_args()
json_args = json.loads(args.json_args)
validate_user(json_args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have already investigated and determined the issue is with the imports then you could skip this, however I would suggest doing some timings and logs of how long the each section of work takes.

```py
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()

# rest of your imports and code between

elapsed_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
# might need to write to file if running from Node
print(elapsed_time) # seconds
```

You can add this to multiple places to help narrow down which part of the script is the bottle-neck.

---

For the imports I suggest checking if you have any code that is running on import that shouldn't be. For example:

```py
# file1.py
import time
def long_running_function():
    time.sleep(5) # simulate lots of work

long_running_function() # note this is being called in the file
```

then in the file you are executing

```py
# file2.py
print('Before import')
import file1
print('After import') # this will take 5 seconds to output
```

To prevent this you should add a main guard

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    long_running_function()
```

This way if you execute `file1.py` standalone `long_running_function` will run, if you import `file1` by running `file2.py` then `long_running_function` will not run.

As you've done in `validate_user.py` setting up the ArgumentParser and calling `validate_user`, if some other file were to import your `validate_user.py` then that would run as well even if you didn't want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't import that python file in nodejs only once and i use it,
for all of your nodejs app lifecycle,

BTW i have written this library for that: [Py3](https://github.com/obaydmerz/py3/)

Simple usage:

```
# simple.py

import json

def validate():
    # props are auto json-ed
    return {'hi': 'hello', 'num': 10, 'bool': True}
```

Other side:

```
// index.js

import { Py } from "py3";

// Create a Py instance
const python = new Py({
  cwd: import.meta.dirname
});

// Execute a simple Python instruction

(async () => {
  await python.waitStart();

  await python.exec("from simple import validate");
  

  // props are auto unjson-ed
  console.log((await python.exec(`validate()`)).hi);
})();
```